# Flex items change width when the text inside them wraps

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I'm trying to format a series of warning messages. Each message is a flexbox made up of 3 flex items: a little color circle (i tag) and then 2 p tags with varying text depending on the warning. I want them all left-justified with consistent spacing between the first p and the second.

The problem is when there is a line break within one of the p elements (when the warning title or description becomes too long), the width of that whole p element changes and extends beyond the right edge of the text, causing a big white space between the left and right p tags.

[Hopefully this image will describe the issue better. The first 4 lines are fine, but on line 5 there is too much space because the width of the first p element expanded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRgMD.jpg)

```css
.warnings {
  width: 600px;
}

.warning {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="warnings">
  <div class="warning">
    <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
    <p class="type">Warning type</p>
    <p class="description">Warning description text goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="warning">
    <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
    <p class="type">Short Warning type</p>
    <p class="description">Warning description text goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="warning">
    <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
    <p class="type">Very long warning looks like this</p>
    <p class="description">Warning description text goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="warning">
    <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
    <p class="type">Warning type</p>
    <p class="description">Warning description text goes here and on and on and on and on and on and on</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `white-space: nowrap`?

Comment: See this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XExdwo.

Comment: I actually do want the text to be able to wrap. It's just that when it wraps, I want the edge of the item to be right up against the edge of the text. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Oh then it's simple, see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `flex-shrink: 3` to the item that should shrink more than the others. That will make the item shrink as much as possible.

```css
.warnings { width: 600px; }
.warning { display: inline-flex; align-items: baseline; }

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p.description {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.type {
  margin: 0 5px;
  flex-shrink: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="warnings">
    <div class="warning">
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        <p class="type">Warning type</p>
        <p class="description">Warning description text goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="warning">
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        <p class="type">Short Warning type</p>
        <p class="description">Warning description text goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="warning">
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        <p class="type">Very long warning looks like this</p>
        <p class="description">Warning description text goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="warning">
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        <p class="type">Warning type</p>
        <p class="description">Warning description text goes here and on and on and on and on and on and on</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's definitely a lot closer! Thanks! The snippet you wrote looks good. However, when applied to the page I'm working on, there are enough variables where the white space still persists. I don't know how to post an image in this comment but basically the problem is still there. Sometimes there's just a ton of extra space in that second flex item.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, when using `flex` on `p`. The workaround I found was
to wrapped the `p` element inside another `div` and widths were correct.

I think when a `p` element gets bigger, despite having a word-wrap, flex thinks it is a bigger element and shrinks the others